# How do I remove partitions in the 'Places' section of the Gnome file dialog?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

In the Gnome file dialog under 'Places' I can add and edit bookmarks to directories. That list however not only contains my bookmarks, but also a list of all partitions on the system that Gnome seems to gather automatically. I can't edit that list as the right-click-menu items for that are greyed out.

How can I get rid of those automatically generated entries or limit it to just my bookmarks?